# Defining two objects at once using list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list of dicationaries `list_dic` each containing the keys `id;name`. From those keys I'd like create two lists.

I would like to use a list comprehension for this task, e.g.

```
list_id = [a['id'] for a in list_dic]
list_name = [a['name'] for a in list_dic]
```

The issue here is I'm looping twice which is probably not a smart thing to do.

Is there a way to use a list comprehension looping only once?

```
# Pseudo
list_id, list_name  = [a['id'], a['name'] for a in list_dic]
```

**PS**

I tried `helper = [[a['id'], a['name']] for a in list_dic]` which almost works. The problem is subsetting seems to require looping yet again (I hoped something like `helper[:][0]` would provide all `ids`).

Comment: i would really consider a plain for loop here: `for a in list_dic: list_id.append(a['id'])` etc. if iterating twice is really a practical issue for you here

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yeah this was so far the only way I came up with to loop just once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
list_id, list_name = zip(*[(a['id'], a['name']) for a in list_dic])
```

Comment: Is this preferable to 2 independent list comps though- unconvinced

Comment: @Chris_Rands, IMO it is for short comprehensions like this. You can even skip the list and use the generator only.

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Im missing the sintax error, would you please point it out? Thanks!

Comment: You just fixed it :)

Comment: @Chris_Rands What makes you prefer 2 list comps?

Comment: @Netwave Thanks! What does the start inside `zip` do?

Comment: @user101, it unpacks the original list.

Comment: so zip is called as `zip((id1, name1), (id2, name2)... )`